# Play a mp3 file from a selected list form

Tags: javascript, audio, menu

I need to select a mp3 or wave file from a pull down menu then play, pause, stop and change volume.
Got started code from W3Cl
It only plays the first selection (Normal) does not play (AR or PS)
Also need to add volume control

`enter code here`

```
<audio id="myTune">
<source src="Normal.mp3">
<source src="AR.mp3">
<source src="PS.mp3">
</audio>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('myTune').play()">Play Music</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('myTune').pause()">Pause Music</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('myTune').pause();        document.getElementById('myTune').currentTime = 0;">Stop Music</button> 


 select name="myTune" onchange='myTune(this.value);'> 
 <option value="Normal.mp3" SELECTED>  Normal              
 <option value="AR.mp3"> Aortic Regurgitation              
 <option value="PS.mp3"> Pulmonary Stenosis
 </select>
 <input type="text" name="myTune" id="myTune" style='display:none;'/>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: you can't re-use IDs like that. plus, myTune is an element, but you're calling it like a function...

Comment: Can you help with some code suggestions I am learning coding and need some guidance